# Directive - Modify DOM in link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to modify the margin of some element in link function.

This is my code:

```
scope.size = (($("#highlight .thumbs li").width() * $("#highlight .thumbs li").size()) + (20 * ($("#highlight.thumbs li").size() - 1)));

elem.find(".thumbs").addClass({ width : scope.size});
```

The thing is: The `scope.size` in the link function is `-20px;`

If I put the code inside the `$timeout()` function with `100` milliseconds delay, I got the real value, which is `252px`;

There is some trick to watch the DOM to get the final value of width or elements inside the template after rendering? I don't want to use `$timeout` to blink the element in the view.

Comment: You have to wait until link function is finished to get the size of element as the element hasn't be inserted into DOM during link function. However, you don't have to wait 100 to do it, you can just ignore the duration, which will execute the code immediately after the link function. What's better? You can even use the native `setTimeout` to set the width in order not to trigger an extra digest cycle (if you don't need to bind scope.size somewhere).

Comment: please post your problem in Fiddle, to let us play with it

Comment: @Daiwei thanks, I tried to use without the time, but still give me the negative value. Can I create a parent or child directive to execute this code after the dom is rendered?

Comment: One of the tradeoffs with Angular's data bindings is there's no final state- on any $digest() something may change- which is why Angular has said they can't provide a "done rendering" event.  But you could do a directive that watches whatever value and then triggers any change you need upon change.

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan I was wrong about the link function. I think the problem is in the function that calculate size. Can you post the code of the directive or create a plnkr? My example works http://plnkr.co/edit/wMrsth?p=preview

Comment: OK, i'm not with my code right now, i'll update asap =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link: { post : function($scope, $element, attributes, controllers, $timeout){
        var listener = $scope.$watch(function(){
            var value = '';
            var inputs = $element.find(':input');

            for(var i = 0;i < inputs.length;i++ ){
                value += ' '+inputs[i].value;
            }

            if(value.trim() == ''){
                $scope.value = $scope.text;
            } else {
                $scope.value = value;
            }
        });
    }}
```

add your code in $scope.$watch(function(){ // your code });

Comment: so, I explain my own code.
I try to get real values from inputs, which not ready.
But in $scope.$watch it's work.

Comment: Nice! It works. The only thing is that I need to unregister the watch after I got the correct value to avoid the watch function to be called in every digest loop. Thanks!

Comment: if you know how unwatch after correct value, please tell me how :D

Comment: if I try 
    listener();
in the end of link function, my code stops working